# Set value of field based on GET param for anonymous users

Tags: 7, forms

I ran into a strange problem. All forms are cached for anonymous users even if there is a token present in the url. But I need that token to store a "value" field type on a form. Because the form is stored in cache, it does not verify for that get param and set the value accordingly.

I tried using an "after_build" function but that is also not triggered.

Is there a way I can use the GET param in my code? Or is there a way I can disable caching only for this form?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at this module [Cache Exclude](https://www.drupal.org/project/cacheexclude), it might help you.

And even have look at [this link](https://www.drupal.org/node/795044), it is having more details about your problem.

Comment: I saw that page also, couldn't use the information there. I haven't tried cache exclude either because I found the problem before that. My form was generated as a block and the block was cached. I had to add `cache = DRUPAL_NO_CACHE` to the block info function.

Comment: Good, I am not aware of that it is block form, I thought that its is a normal menu callback, so I suggested this Cache Exclude module

Answer (score 1):

I found my answer. My form was part of a block that was being cached by Drupal. I had to add `"cache" = DRUPAL_NO_CACHE` to the block info function to stop the block from being cached. After that, everything worked as expected.